# How can we set repeatinterval for UIlocalNotifications biweekly (twice in a month)?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

How can we set repeatinterval for UIlocalNotifications biweekly (twice in a month)?

```
UILocalNotification *local = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
local.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
```

I have set it to weekday, but is there any option for setting notification to fire on every

1st/15th of a month?

Comment: You can't. The only workaround is to use (in your case) two notifications repeating monthly.

Comment: yeah, I try with 2 notifications monthly. Thanks.